# In Windows, is there a visual indicator for applications that are "run as different user"?

Tags: windows

In Windows, is there a way to visually determine that an application is being run as a different user?

By visually, I mean on/in the application's window(s).  At a minimum, this should be for the window which currently has focus.  It would be desirable for the same kind of indicator to be available on/in the window of any program window.

If there is no default way, some other option to cause the application to be distinct by user?

I often run multiple instances of the same program as different users.  The various users are associated with different scopes of work responsibility.

There are differences in how tasks are to be done depending on which account is being used.  Sometimes the procedural differences are "subtle but important" between user accounts, so it is important to be certain that an operation is being performed as the correct user.

The use of multiple accounts are dictated by the organization's system administration policies and procedures.

I would like to be sure that the operation is being performed in the correct context.

I would like to have a visual cue to show which account is running the instance of the application.

Some examples of alternative solutions are not acceptable for the purposes of this question:

- Performing a "switch user"
- Putting the applications instance in different areas of the screen or on different monitors

The distinction should not require any manual intervention on the part of the user once the application is started.

I simply want to be sure that I'm doing something as the user as which I expect to be doing it.

Comment: No;  There isn't.  A Windows User for the most part is unaware there are even other Users that might exist.  The most awareness is a notification if another User had logged in without logging out ( since switch user was used )

Comment: Task Manager, although not directly, does show what process is running in a given user.

Comment: Often,  knowing the reason for a question can help provide an answer. Why are you asking?

Comment: I only found this for Explorer and IE: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2011/09/01/privbar-update.aspx

Comment: You wrote "visually"... Is it possible to be more accurate? Unless, I can say that Task Manager give you this information "visually"... What are you looking exactly: an icon on task bar or in the application window or... ? :)

Comment: re: "visually" - edited to address.  I don't believe that Task Manager tells which "window" is being run by which user.  It tell which "process", but there is no association between processes and Windows.  Only "Applications" and Windows with "Switch To".  However, the application list doesn't include a user.

Comment: The IE option seems promising for IE.  I'm looking for this for any windowed application.

Comment: Actually, there is. If each process is run by a different user, then a window should appear for each user. You can check if the window you selected in Task Manager is the one you want by right-clicking the entry in Task Manager and then going to process. This is understandably tedious, however.

Comment: @Doktoro Reichard - good to know.  However, too much of cognitive and workflow disruption (and, of course, not a visual cue in the application window(s)).  Thanks for the tip.