# Visual indicator that explorer is running as administrator

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, administrator, user-interface

Under Windows 7, I open an explorer window as administrator. How can I tell that this explorer window has admin privileges?

Either a visual indicator (e.g. an annotation on the icon or in the title bar) or some simple way of finding out (e.g. via a menu entry) would do.

[This unanswered question](https://superuser.com/questions/852166/in-windows-is-there-a-visual-indicator-for-applications-that-are-run-as-differ) asks for a more general feature; I'm primarily interested in Explorer. [This related question](https://superuser.com/questions/949439/how-to-know-an-application-is-run-as-administrator-if-it-doesnt-show-that-in-i) asks about an *application*; this is not good enough for me since I have both admin and unprivileged instances of Explorer running: I need per-window information.

Answer (score 2):

`Aaron Margosis` wrote an E[xtension to show in Internet Explorer and Windows Explorer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaron_margosis/2011/09/01/privbar-update/) its current elevation/IL level status:

- Low IL = protected mode
  [image: Low IL screenshot]
- Medium IL = normal operation
  [image: Medium IL screenshot]
- High IL = administrator
  [image: High IL screenshot]

Expand the Zip and register the DLLs with regsvr32:

```
regsvr32 path\PrivBar.dll
regsvr32 path\PrivBarx64.dll
```

Then enable the toolbar from the menu: “View” → “Toolbars” → “PrivBar” (or “PrivBar x64”, whichever appears). Repeat this in Internet Explorer to get the toolbar there as well.

Comment: Thanks. I've activated the toolbars and they always show “Medium IL” now, but explorer is apparently running as administrator since I can create a directory in `c:\`. I see Medium and apparent admin privileges whether I run Explorer simply by clicking on the icon/filename or I use “Run as administrator” and get a UAC prompt. Is my test for admin mode wrong or is PrivBar wrong?

Comment: By default it is blocked to run Explorer as admin. You need to unlock it. [Use my hack](https://superuser.com/a/594641/174557) to allow Explorer to be running as admin.

Comment: Evidently I did manage to run Explorer with some kind of privileges, because initially I couldn't create a directory under `c:\ ` and after selecting “run as administrator” in the start menu I could create that directory. But the user interface does confuse me. This is on a corporate install which may have different settings from a default Windows 7 installation.

Comment: you don't need admin rights to create new folders. you nee admin rights to store files in C: or edit the files there.

Comment: any update? Does it work the way you want it?

Comment: It still shows me “Medium IL” and I don't understand whether it's running as admin or not. When I don't have urgent work I'll try rebooting to see if this is the effect of cached credentials somewhere.

Comment: and what is your issue? this means it runs as normal user, NO admin . Is this SOOOOO hard to understand. I see you are a *nix user, but you should understand medium = normal user, high = admin.